# JComboBox Item List

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am wondering how would I change the name of the item list in my JComboBox?here's my code
I want to change it to Dog, Panda, bee. rather than choosing their path.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class ComboTest {

    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JComboBox comboImage;

    private String[] names = {"images/dog.gif","images/bee.gif","images/Panda.gif"};
    private Icon[] icons = {
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(names[0])),
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(names[1])),
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(names[2])),
    };

    public ComboTest(){
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Combo");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(320, 160);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        comboImage = new JComboBox(names);
        comboImage.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    imageLabel.setIcon(icons[comboImage.getSelectedIndex()]);
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(comboImage);
        imageLabel = new JLabel(icons[0]);
        frame.add(imageLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: why-o-why dont they read any longer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: Since I don't know what your goal is, why can't you declare names = {"Dog","Bee","Panda"}; ? 
So your question is how to associate "Dog" to "images/dog.gif" am I correct?

Comment: this is not a homework. I am coding for fun.. , @themrz I never though of that. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to make an object with two properties, the path and the text you want to display.

Then you'll set the `toString` method to return the text property. Disclaimer: I haven't tested any of this code.

```
public class ValueText {
   private String text;
   private String value;

   public ValueText(final String text, final String value) {
      this.text = text;
      this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return text;
   }

   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }
}
```

Then you can change your initial array to something like:

```
private Object[] names = {
   new ValueText("Dog", "images/dog.gif"),
   new ValueText("Bee", "images/bee.gif"),
   new ValueText("Panda", "images/Panda.gif")
};
```

And it should work similarly, only now, when you are inspecting the selected item, you can use the `getValue()` method to get the path.

You also might be interested in a custom renderer, but it's probably not necessary for your use:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

**Update** I'll go ahead and make a correction after kleopatra made some convincing arguments in the comments, which you should read below.

A more general purpose and cleaner way of doing this is with a custom renderer, even if it's very simple (see link above).

Comment: thanks for your effort, but don't you think this is quite long for a simple operation?

Comment: @user962206: A simpler way is to perhaps use a HashMap<String, String>, but having said that, Wes's recommendations are quite valid and while your current case may be a trivial example, his methods can be applied to much more complex examples later. I suggest that you follow his advice 1+ up-vote.

Comment: -1 a wrapper class and overriding its toString is not the recommended way - a custom renderer is what you need

Comment: @kleopatra If he's only trying to use strings in the combobox itself (ie. "Dog"), I don't see why you need a custom renderer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You're right, ha. That would be a more concise way of achieving the objective. Even with more complex examples, you could use a HashMap<String, Object>. If you put that as an answer I'd vote for it. I was focusing on using the existing JComboBox methods.

Comment: @kleopatra: Either way he should create a wrapper class.

Comment: @Hovercraft - no, why should he? The combo just shows a certain visual representation of the file (and/or icon, whatever). That's what a renderer is designed for, the exact place to implement ... @ Wes - and what do you do if you want to have different visual reps in different views? Certainly not different wrappers with differently overridden toString methods ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra: The combo may need to show the String that represents what the image file holds (and the OP is attempting to do just that). In his current example a sort-of OK String can be extracted from his image file path String, but this isn't always the case. A wrapper class could help tie image file path and its String representation together. /Pete

Comment: @Hovercraft - should have been more clear: a wrapper class which does nothing but override the toString is The-Wrong-Thing (never-ever override toString for view reasons, it's a dirty hack) A wrapper which has additional properties (such as the method getValue(..) above) _plus_ a renderer which uses that method is fine.

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah, you convinced me, too. I started working on some example code, but then I realized that his code looks almost like the example scenario in the tutorial. Hmm.