# How to hide jcombobox item from list but still use it to get data from databse tables

Tags: java, jquery, database, swing, jcombobox

Hello so somehow managed to make that id isn't shown in combobox , but then how to make that when I press button ok I could get id value? Using

```
String from = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
```

when button is pressed doesn't work... I get

```
String code = (String) item.getValue();
```

the id i needed but how I pass it to the next query?

```
public void select() {
     try {
        String sql = "select * from category";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

    jComboBox1.addItem(new Item<String>(rs.getString("mkid"), rs.getString("name")));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox jComboBox1 = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            Item item = (Item) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            String code = (String) item.getValue();
            System.out.println(code);
        }
    });


}


The item

 public class Item<V> implements Comparable<Item>
 {
private V value;
private String description;


public Item(V value, String description)
{
    this.value = value;
    this.description = description;
}


public V getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}

public int compareTo(Item item)
{
    return getDescription().compareTo(item.getDescription());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    Item item = (Item)object;
    return value.equals(item.getValue());
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return value.hashCode();
}


@Override
public String toString()
{
    return description;
}
```

Comment: create a new class which has JCombobox as parent and has a private variable `id`

Comment: You need to do something similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053927/jcombobox-item-list)

Comment: And you might want to [read how to use JCombobox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom Object to contain your data and then add the custom Object to the model. You then need to use a custom renderer to display this Object.

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this and I read Combo Box With Custom Renderer few times but still don't understand what to do. And i did read about how to use JCombobox, but still I'm missing something :(